# Add OR WHERE statement in codeigniter using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework and i want to create a OR WHERE statement using foreach loop,

Below is my code,

```
$wh_q = array('ec_date >' => $start, 'ec_date <=' => $end);
```

This will produce query as `WHERE ec_details.date > '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND ec_details.date <= '2017-01-07 00:00:00'`

Now i want to append few more criteria in abover query string with AND `ec_details`.`user_id` = '5' OR `ec_details`.`user_id` = '6' and so on.

Now user_id, 5 and 6 are coming from array results,

```
$user_string = '5,6';
$users_array = explode(",",$user_string);

foreach ($users_array as $user) {
   $query = array('ec_details.user_id' => $user);
}
```

Then i am merging above `$query` array in original `$wh_q` array

```
$wh_q = array_merge($wh_q, $query);
```

And finally i select where as below,

```
$this->db->where($wh_q);
```

But this will not produce my required query, but will just create like below,

```
`WHERE `ec_details`.`date` > '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND `ec_details`.`date` <= '2017-01-07 00:00:00'`AND `ec_details`.`user_id` = '6'`
```

How can i add AND OR WHERE statements using foreach loop in codeigniter?

Thank you,

Comment: I assume you want to get details from ec_detail table for user_id 5 and 6 between start and end range, is that it?

Comment: @MalikMudassar, yes correct

Comment: see edited answer...if works accept it thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below...

```
$wh_q = array('ec_date >' => $start, 'ec_date <=' => $end);//condition first

$user_string = '5,6';
$users_array = explode(",",$user_string);

foreach ($users_array as $user) {
   $query []= array('ec_details.user_id' => $user);//second condition
}

//print_r($query) //multidimensional array
```

Query

```
$this->db->where($wh_q);

$total = count($query);
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
    $this->db->or_where($query[$i]);
    }
```

Comment: but this will not add value 5, it will just generate -- OR `ec_expensedetails`.`user_id` = '6', where as i need -- AND `ec_expensedetails`.`user_id` = '5' OR `ec_expensedetails`.`user_id` = '6'

Comment: what if we use $query.= array('ec_details.user_id' => $user);

no, that will create 2 OR statements

Comment: @Hikmat, is same key allowed in array? no its not. I think we can only achieve with custom string..

Comment: @HikmatSijapati, no it will not work, will produce OR 0 = `Array` OR 1 = `Array`

Comment: That will still produce two OR statements @Hikmat, but I guess it should get the required results

Comment: @HikmatSijapati, yes it solved issue but i just changed $this->db->or_where($query[0]); to $this->db->where($query[0]); so condition will start with WHERE instead of OR, btw need to look on some more because we don't count number of $users_array,

Comment: @HikmatSijapati, my question is simple, if assume $user_string = '5,6,7,8,9'; and more....then i can not manually add more or_where condition as $user_string is user input and it's length can be more or less!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,
create a complete where string like this

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

And check, this will work.

**EDIT**

OR you can give or condition like this

```
$this->db->where('name !=', $name);
$this->db->or_where('id >', $id);  // Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' OR id > 50
```

Comment: @V for Vendetta, this can work if we do as string, but we need to pull values from array and create conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you you need to check only user id then better you can also user IN like below.

```
$user_string = '5,6'; $users_array = explode(",",$user_string); 
$this->db->where_in('id', $users_array);
```

and If you want to use only OR and And statement

then use below code

```
$this->db->where('ec_date >',$start,false);
$this->db->where('ec_date <=', $end,false);
$user_string = '5,6';
$users_array = explode(",",$user_string);
$userqry = array();
foreach ($users_array as $user) {
   $userqry[] = "ec_details.user_id ='".$user."'";
}
$userqrystr = implode(" OR ",  $userqry);
$this->db->where($userqrystr,false,false);
```

This query look like

```
WHERE `ec_details`.`date` > '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND `ec_details`.`date` <= '2017-01-07 00:00:00' AND (`ec_details`.`user_id` = '6' OR `ec_details`.`user_id` = '5')
```